# Best practices for low power consumption (battery operated) I2C pullups

Tags: stm32, i2c, battery-operated, best-practice

I'm working on a battery powered device and am trying to extend battery life by using a lot of interrupt and timer driven code on the microcontroller (keeping it sleeping most of the time) and putting the sensors to sleep as often as practical.

My question is about pullups on the I2C bus.  I am using an STM32L432 microcontroller, and I2C in low-speed operation.  I have considered using PFETs to switch on and off the 3V3 rail voltage to the 4k7 pullup resistors (700uA per pullup resistor).  I have also considered using a digital output pin from the STM32 to power the pullups.  From the datasheet, the STM32L432 can source 20mA from an IO pin.  There would of course need to be a "setup time" in either case for the pullup resistors to be energized before the I2C was used.

For those who have experience in this area, I would really appreciate your feedback.  From a "hobbyist" perspective it seems fine to use the digital output to power the pullups, and also reduces parts count.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The idle condition of I2C is with both lines high. There will be no current flowing through the pull-ups when the bus is not being used. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: Apologies for the oversight!  I've now sized the pullups per TI SLVA689.  Thank you @KevinWhite for your assistance

Comment: @KevinWhite I believe there will be leakage current through pull-ups even if port is not used. But at about 150 nA it can certainly be ignored.

Comment: If you turn off the pull-ups, what happens next? If you keep the sensor on, and the I2C pins are floating, would floating CMOS inputs wiggle randomly between logic high and low so the bus has invalid transactions or chips have increased current consumption due to voltage floating at undefined levels. Are you planning to keep internal pull-ups enabled or turn off all sensors on the bus too?

Comment: @KevinWhite maybe you could transform your comment to a full answer so it can be accepted and this topic closed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the I2C peripherals are to remain powered during processor sleep then there is no need to remove power from the I2C pull-ups, they will not be taking any current above the sub-microamp leakage current. Probably low enough to be ignored.

The idle state of I2C when not being used is both lines at a logic one.

If you wish to power down the I2C pull-ups or I2C peripherals to reduce power be aware of the following.

If an I2C peripheral is powered down it will probably drag both I2C lines as well (because of ESD structures at the inputs of the device). This will probably create an illegal I2C state and force you to re-initialize all devices on the bus (even those that didn't get powered down) when the power is restored. It will at least require the usual I2C bus reset approach of nine clock pulses with the data line high, that may not be enough though.

If you need to power down a device then it would be recommended to power down all the devices on that I2C pus and remove power from the pull-ups as well. Powering them all from a GPIO output may be acceptable but you will have to determine if there is enough current available and that the voltage drop is acceptable during operation.

If you wish to only power down only one I2C device then you could put it on a dedicated I2C bus with the others on a separate one. Even if the processor only has a single I2C bus you can create a software I2C master with a pair of GPIOs.